# Why is a list of transforms within a class deleted when the class instance gets copied to a list?

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I have this problem in Unity (or maybe C#) that's very weird to me. Here is a virtual class:

```
public abstract class ActionTaken : MonoBehaviour {
    protected char type;
    protected Transform minionTakingAction;
    public abstract void activate();
}
```

And this virtual class is a parent to the one that interests me:

```
public class AbilityTaken : ActionTaken
{
    public int index;
    List<Transform> selectedFriendlyMinions;
    List<Transform> selectedEnemyMinions;
    List<Transform> selectedTiles;
    public override void activate()
    {
        //The value here is 0 !!! And it should be 1...
        Debug.Log(selectedEnemyMinions.Count);
        if (selectedFriendlyMinions.Count == 0 && selectedEnemyMinions.Count == 0 && selectedTiles.Count == 0 )
        {
            minionTakingAction.GetComponentInParent<AbilitiesActivation>().activateAbility(index);
        }
        else
        {
            minionTakingAction.GetComponentInParent<AbilitiesActivation>().activateAbility(index, selectedFriendlyMinions, selectedEnemyMinions, selectedTiles);
        }
    }

    public AbilityTaken(Transform _minionTakingAction, int abilityIndex, List<Transform> _selectedFriendlyMinions, List<Transform> _selectedEnemyMinions, List<Transform> _selectedTiles) 
    {
        type = 'S'; 
        minionTakingAction = _minionTakingAction;
        index = abilityIndex;
        selectedEnemyMinions = _selectedEnemyMinions;
        selectedFriendlyMinions = _selectedFriendlyMinions;
        selectedTiles = _selectedTiles;
        //The value here is 1 !!!
        Debug.Log(selectedEnemyMinions.Count);
    }
    public AbilityTaken(Transform _minionTakingAction, int abilityIndex)
    {
        type = 'S';
        minionTakingAction = _minionTakingAction;
        index = abilityIndex;
        selectedFriendlyMinions = new List<Transform>();
        selectedEnemyMinions = new List<Transform>();
        selectedTiles = new List<Transform>();
    }
}
```

As you can see in the comments, the value of selectedEnemyMinions list of Transforms changes from the constructor (count value: 1) to the "activate()" function (count value: 0), without me making any changes to it. All I do is:
1. I create a new instance of AbilityTaken giving to the constructor an enemyMinionSelection list with 1 element
2. I add abilityTaken to a list
3. I call activate() from LateUpdate()

```
AbilityTaken abilityTaken = new AbilityTaken(minionTakingAction, gameMaster.abilitySelected,
                       // value of enemyMinionSelected.Count here is 1
 new List<Transform>(), gameMaster.enemyMinionsSelected, new List<Transform>());
List<ActionsTaken> actionsTaken = new List<ActionTaken>();
actionsTaken.Add(abilityTaken);

private void LateUpdate()
{
    if (!actionInProgress &&
        actionsTaken.Count>0)
    {
        ActionTaken currentAction = actionsTaken[0];
        currentAction.activate();
    }
}
```

If you can tell me why adding the class instance to List and accessing this instance would cause a member List of Transforms to change their value, that would be great. On the other hand the value of member variable "index" doesn't change (it's always 1). I tried changing Lists to public but that doesn't help as expected.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. Why are you creating a new instance via the constructor? If the class derives from `MonoBehaviour`, you should *never* create a new instance with `new`, but rather with `Instantiate` or `AddComponent` and initialize it in the `Awake` or `Start` method.

Comment: I am not sure if it should be MonoBehaviour but it should not be linked to a particular game object. There could be multiple instances of ActionTaken that generate when ever the player makes a selection and uses an ability.

Comment: The whole idea is to add a list of pending actions that have to be resolved at the beginning of the next turn and they can be activated by various minions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thoroughly debugged my code and found that the problem here is that I am giving the 
 constructor of ActionTaken parameters (Namely List) that get changed after assignment in ActionTaken constructor. Then I execute some code that changes the first list of transforms, but due to C# not copying the value, but referencing the assigned value the List of Transforms changes when the firstly assigned value changes.

```
void function()
{
//Some code here
      AbilityTaken abilityTaken = new AbilityTaken(minionTakingAction, gameMaster.abilitySelected, new List<Transform>(), gameMaster.enemyMinionsSelected, new List<Transform>())
//Here we go in the constructor and everything seems fine
// ! Some code here that changes gameMaster.enemyMinionsSelected. The class object doesn't copy the List of Transforms, but references it's address and when it changes, the reference in ActionTaken also changes.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> If you can tell me why adding the class instance to List and accessing this instance would cause a member List of Transforms to change their value, that would be great.

It's not. There's nothing wrong with doing that, it won't change the current values of AbilityTaken.

There is something else going on, that is, the problem is somewhere else. For example, `Debug.Log(selectedEnemyMinions);` is not printing the **Count**.

Comment: Nope that's a typo. I actually wrote Debug.Log(selectedEnemyMinions.Count) as I did everywhere else.

Comment: I stand by what I said though. There's something else modifying your list. Add a call to `activate()` after the creation of your instance, it should print 1 and them something else is modifying the list (or creating a new one).  Also, Ian is right, you *can't* make it a MonoBehaviour and have a constructor - this is actually the most important thing, you need to change it now. Btw, you shouldn't call GetComponent inside a LateUpdate loop, for performance reasons.

Comment: I agree. I removed the MonoBehaviour as I should have and thank you for telling me that I shouldn't call GetComponent in the LateUpdate(). I suppose it's the same for calling it in Update() ? Anyway I debugged my problem thoroughly and I found the problem and a solution, which I will post as an answer.